# Merge two lists into one in non-descending order

Tags: python, recursion

```
def merge (l1,l2):

    if l2 == [] and l2 == []:
        return [] 
    if l1 == []:
        return sorted(l2)
    if l2 == [] :
        return sorted(l1)

    if l1[0]<= l2[0]:
        return merge(l1[1:],l2)
    else:
        return merge(l1,l2[1:])
```

I am writing a recursive function named merge; it is passed two list arguments (each is guaranteed to contain the same type of values and each is sorted in non-descending order) it returns a new list containing all the values from both argument lists, in non-descending order.

The call `merge([0,1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8,9])` returns  `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

But my function returns `[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to **keep** the smallest element:

```
if l1[0]<= l2[0]:
    return [l1[0]] + merge(l1[1:],l2)
else:
    return [l2[0]] + merge(l1,l2[1:])
```

---

Another comment: If you want them merged you don't need the `sorted`-calls (it should be sorted already) if an iterable is empty.